# Некорректно отображается поля

Tags: vue.js

Использую в своей форме поле type
На windows в обычных браузерах это поле имеет формат, по которому надо вводить дату. Там вводимые данные подстраиваются в нужный формат автоматически.
Странно, что параметр HTML не поддерживается Safari

Пожалуйста, предлагайте конкретные фрагменты кода или ссылки на ресурсы.
Спасибо

Comment: Зачем вандалить?

Comment: Не следует вандализировать собственные вопросы. Особенно, если уже дан ответ.

Comment: Имею право. Всё-таки мой вопрос

Comment: @Владислав.С уже нет. Вопрос теперь принадлежит сообществу. Своим вандализмом вы мешаете другим участникам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброй ночи.

Вот таблица совместимости HTML элементов с браузерами:

https://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local

Как видите поле не работает с сафари, IE и firefox десктопных.

Вам потребуется связка https://modernizr.com/ (для определения что браузер не может обработать datetime-local) и плагина jquery для реализации функционала выбора даты и времени.

**UPD. (ответ на комментарий)**

> Я только не очень понял, как использовать modernizr

- Идете сюда:
  https://modernizr.com/download?inputtypes-setclasses&q=form%20input%20types
- Вводите в поиск form input types, жмете на плюсик в найденном для добавления функционала в build
- Жмете BUILD
- Если вы работаете без CMD или GRUNT - жмете download напротив build
- Получаете скрипт минимального веса для проверки конкретно вашей задачи.
- Подключаете его в свой код.
- Используете как показано ниже.

Вот, как мне кажется, приемлемый вариант плагина выбора даты времени. Он позволяет настроить нужное форматирование: 
https://xdan.ru/samij-udobnij-datetimepicker.html

**UPD. (ответ на комментарий)**

> Плагин интересный, правда боюсь его ставить, вдруг страницу сильно
>   нагрузит. И я так понял, что он не задаёт жёсткую рамку для ввода, как
>   datetime-local, а просто её считывает?

Страницу он сильно не нагрузит. Он проверяет форматирование. Т.е. можно ввести глупость вида "asd", но она заменится после ввода.

Посмотрите демо чтобы лучше понять: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
Можете любой другой выбрать, например вот платный с масками где не дают вводить глупости: 
Демо: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/calendar-popup/

Код в итоге будет примерно таким:

```
<script>
    <!--
    if(!Modernizr.inputtypes['datetime-local']) {
        $('input[type=datetime-local]').datetimepicker();
    }
    -->
</script>
```

В datetimepicker() нужно через опции передать требуемое вам форматирование даты и времени + задать нужные вам языковые настройки. По ссылке выше есть вся необходимая документация и примеры.

Использовать webshim polyfill к сожалению не получится для этого формата т.к он не обеспечивает правильную работу datetime-local http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/

```
$.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

Вот ссылка на песочницу где можно поиграться с параметрами polifyll и убедиться что он не обеспечивает нужного функционала в firefox:

https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-datetime-local.html#min=&max=&list=&step=&value=&startView=0&minView=0&stepfactor=&useDecadeBase=0&startValue=&calculateWidth=on&popover=&popover=&popover=

**Ссылки по теме**

Обсуждение проблемы на англоязычном стаке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028108/html-5-input-datetime-local-any-browser-ios-9-native-date-time-picker-how-to-s?rq=1

Мысли разработчиков Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/datetime-local

Comment: ☝ Полезная песочница и инфо)))

Comment: Можно заранее уточнить, пока я не углубился в тему. Этот элемент поможет мне сделать кроссбраузерность этому элементу или он сможет мне заменить это поле, но оставить ввод данных с него в таком формате. А то уже очень много алгоритмов на моём сайте связано именно с таким форматом даты, который выдаёт поле Datetime-local. Можно ли как-то сделать всё безболезненно?)

Comment: @Владислав.С Я перепроверил всё, после вашего комментария. В конкретно вашем случае вебшим не подойдет. Перепишу сейчас ответ под рабочее решение.

Comment: @adudnik.ru Спасибо, буду ждать рабочее решение)

Comment: @Владислав.С посмотрите, надеюсь это то, что вы ищите.

Comment: @adudnik.ru Плагин интересный, правда боюсь его ставить, вдруг страницу сильно нагрузит. И я так понял, что он не задаёт жёсткую рамку для ввода, как datetime-local, а просто её считывает? Я только не очень понял, как использовать modernizr.

Comment: @Владислав.С обновил ответ под ваши вопросы.

Comment: @adudnik.ru Почти разобрался. Осталось только вот что. Мне надо, чтобы пользователь вводил данные в таком формате 20.02.2020 18:30, но значение из этого поля передавалось как 20.02.2020T18:30 Как это сделать, чтобы пользователю не было видно этого Т?

Comment: @Владислав.С обычный replace пробела на букву Т должен решить эту проблему. Можете прям в modernizr дописать изменение перед отправкой формы или настроить маску так, чтобы между данными стояла буква Т (если работаете с данными через JS).

Comment: @adudnik.ru. Возможно, я не до конца понял суть скрипта, возможно установил не правильно, хотя сделал всё по документации, но если ввести 20.12.2020 18:30, то не конвертирует введенную строчку в 2020.12.20 18:30

Comment: @Владислав.С напишите мне в whatsapp 904 689 20 81 ссылку на ресурс - попробую помочь.

Comment: @adudnik.ru А у вас случайно нет телеграмма?

Comment: @Владислав.С тот же номер.

Comment: @adudnik.ru Написал в телеграмм